# Why can't I ping my new Amazon Web Service EC2 Windows instance, even with security group with ICMP enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security-groups

There are several questions asking the same thing, but they are all 6+ years old so I thought I'd ask again in case something has changed. The AWS EC2 docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html?shortFooter=true#sg-rules-ping) also make it look simple; just add the ICMP rule, which I've done. I've actually added 2 rules, one for Request, one for Response, based on some of the answers to those other questions. Still doesn't work.

Also, I AM able to connect via Remote Desktop to the instance.

After an answer, I have turned off Windows firewall on the instance, for both public and private networks, since it's behind the AWS Security Group as well. Still can not get a ping response.

Is there a delay when a Security Group rule changes?  Do you have to restart your instance for these to take effect? Anything like that?

Comment: Does your instance have its own firewall that is blocking pings?

Comment: I have no idea, how would I determine that? I'm new to AWS; just went through a 3 day class at work, and so I'm playing around with my own free tier stuff; I just followed the steps in the Getting Started with EC2 guide, so most things are defaults, except for the Security group

Comment: What OS are you using on your instance? Choices include Amazon Linux, Ubuntu, CentOS, etc. Outside of AWS, what do you know about server administration?

Comment: Windows instance, free tier; don't know much else about server admin, beyond what I've dabbled in in 20 years of software engineering

Comment: I didn't know you could do Windows on the free tier. In any case, you need to check the Windows firewall. It is probably set to disallow pings.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found that on a new Windows Server instance in AWS you had to change the Windows Firewall to allow ICMP through the Windows Firewall before you could ping the instance.

Beyond that the main options are:

- No internet gateway
- Subnet routing table not set up to point at internet gateway
- Security groups blocking traffic
- Network ACLs (NACLs) blocking traffic (they are open by default)